# Uploading multiple images on server reaches one less

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, image, upload

When I try to upload multiple images from array, for example 3 image, on server uploads only 2. If I upload 2, get 1 and if 1, no images uploads at all. What is wrong with my code?

From `_arrImage` array I get correct amount of images.

Here is objective c:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/upload.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *dataForm = [NSMutableData data];

    if([_arrImage count] > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        for (NSDictionary *imageDic in _arrImage) {
            UIImage *myimage = [imageDic objectForKey:@"mainImage"];
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myimage, 0.8);
            [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload[]\"; filename=\"%d.jpg\"\r\n",  i] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [dataForm appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
            i++;
        }
    }

    [request setHTTPBody:dataForm];

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {

        if(data.length > 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }] resume];
```

And php is:

```
<?php  
    $uploadFolder = "users/posts/";
    if (!file_exists($uploadFolder)) {
        mkdir($uploadFolder);
    }

    if (is_array($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
        $numberOfFiles = count($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfFiles; $i++) { 
            $uploadFile = $uploadFolder . "/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($uploadFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            if (!(getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i]) !== false)) {
                echo "Sorry, your image is invalid";
                exit;
            }

            if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"][$i] > 10000000) {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                exit;
            }

            if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
                echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                exit;
            }

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $uploadFile)) {
                echo "Upload image ".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i])." successfully!";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

So can you help to figure out the problem.

Here is output of $_FILES if I upload 2 image:

```
$_FILES = array (
  'fileToUpload' => 
  array (
    'name' => 
    array (
      0 => '0.jpg',
      1 => '1.jpg',
    ),
    'type' => 
    array (
      0 => 'image/jpeg',
      1 => '',
    ),
    'tmp_name' => 
    array (
      0 => '/tmp/phpknUF0r',
      1 => '',
    ),
    'error' => 
    array (
      0 => 0,
      1 => 3,
    ),
    'size' => 
    array (
      0 => 39270,
      1 => 0,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I don't know Objective C, but your PHP references `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]`. I don't see "fileToUpload" anywhere in the client-side code.

Comment: [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload[]\"; filename=\"%d.jpg\"\r\n",  i] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Sorry, missed that! First thing you should do is `var_dump($_POST)`. If you see all the files there, you know it's a PHP problem. If you see files missing, it's an ObjC problem

Comment: in logs get warning: PHP Warning:  getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /upload.php on line 15

Comment: Did you try to see `$_FILES` with `print_r`?

Comment: I added $_FILES output to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your objective-c code add

```
        [dataForm appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        i++;
    }

    [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}
```

after the for-loop. It will close the transmitted form-data.